# React JS Custom Filter Pane

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to create a custom filter pane in React.JS as practice, but I am lost and do not know where to begin. I looked online and saw that you could create a filter bar online with a search bar, and while that is nice, I wanted to have multiple buttons to filter different things. For example, if I were to filter an option for shirts, I would like to filter the prospects for the price, graphics on the shirt or without, and the brand of the shirt. Any ideas are welcome! I don't have any code to display because I don't know where to start other than a button and handleChange method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats very abstract situation, but here is how I would do it.

1. Plan what filters you want to have, try to imagine how it should look and work.
2. Get some data set from backend or from hardcoded data, so you will have what to work with.
3. Create component that will display that items.
4. Create UI for filters
5. Then you add logic for filters. On select some filter, you will filter data that comes into your component that provides data to component that display items. Filter that data and your component will display filtered data.

So all structure might look like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({})
  const data = ...

  const filteredData = applyFilters(data, filters) 
  return (
    <div>
      <DisplayItems data={filteredData} />
      <Filters ... />
    </div>

  )
}
```

Its just a basic example for little understanding.

Hope it helps

Comment: So is Filters imported from a child’s js file? Is so, it’s just the hardcoded data on that file correct?

Comment: You might want to have some hardcoded set of filters so you know what people can filter. Also you may have it downloaded from backend, or even have some filters that will be generated automatically, its all up to you and depends only on situation